# Why are the SpaceX Starship, "rings" the width that they are?

Tags: spacex, design, spacex-starship, manufacturing, structural-design

Why are the SpaceX Starship, "rings" the width that they are? Wouldn't creating the rings from SS that's twice as wide reduce the welding by half?

Comment: building it out of a single really wide ring would remove most of the welding

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that's simply the biggest width that you can buy rolls of steel in. IIRC, the width used to be smaller in the beginning.

Answer (score 10):

The largest commercially available width of a roll of stainless steel in the United States is 72 inches.  Apparently this is a standard size, and getting something larger would be a custom order, and not quickly and easily available.

The vendor [Outokumpu](https://www.outokumpu.com/en) (determined by photos of rolls, and the logo found upon them.  Very similar to Lucents Brown Ring of Quality for the 2000's) sells 72 inch rolls.

Comment: I take it then, if SpaceX is successful, they may in the future have enough pull on the manufacture to ask for custom-built SS, even if it requires spending millions building special equipment.

Comment: In general if you are willing to order enough, the vendor will invest.  How much is enough is the question.